# Extracting greek characters from technical PDF documents when using Python 3

Tags: csv, python-3.x, pdf, unicode

I'm currently trying to construct a database of chemicals used in a university department, and their hazard classes. I then wish to output to a csv file. One step is to pull all the synonyms for the various chemicals from standard PDFs, such as this for gamma hexalactone:

[sample PDF](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=GB&language=en&productNumber=W255602&brand=ALDRICH&PageToGoToURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fsearch%3Fterm%3Dgamma%2Bhexalactone%26interface%3DAll%26N%3D0%26mode%3Dmatch%2520partialmax%26lang%3Den%26region%3DGB%26focus%3Dproduct)

At the moment, the code I'm using to extract the text just loses the greek characters which I need to transfer. It looks like this:

```
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(inpathf) txtObj = '' for pageNum in range (0, pdfReader.numPages):

                pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
                txtObj += str(pageObj.extractText())

            inpathf.close()
            outputf.write(txtObj)
            outputf.close()

            return txtObj
```

Parameters are extracted from ~2000 PDFs and stored in a dictionary before being transferred to a csv file:

```
def Outfile_csv(outfile, dict1, length):
outputfile = open((outfile) + '.csv', 'w', newline ='')

output_list = []


outputWriter = csv.writer(outputfile)
outputWriter.writerow(['PDF file', 'Name', 'Synonyms', 'CAS No.', 'H statements',
                       'TWA limits /ppm', 'STEL limits /ppm'])

for r in range (0, length):
    output_list =[]

    for s in range (0,7):
        if s == 0 or s == 3:
            output_list.append(str((dict1[s][r])).encode('utf-8'))
        else:           
            output_list.append(str(dict1[s][r]))

    outputWriter.writerow(output_list)



outputfile.close()
```

I also can't read out to the CSV in cases where there are greek characters - those data are simply not placed in the csv file. Many thanks for any help - a day playing with codecs and the contents of stackexchange has not helped yet. I'm using Python 3.4 and Windows 8.